# How to work with non-ORM models in laravel?

Tags: laravel, model

A model is an object that has only state and no behavior, used in business logic.

Eloquent-ORM models fall under this definition. And under the same definition falls the PlotOptions class, which provides values for drop-down menus and has nothing to do with the database.

```
class PlotOptions {

    public array $water = ["...", "...", "..."];
    public array $gas = ["...", "..."];
    public array $electricity = ["...", "...", "...", "..."];
    public array $sewer = ["...", "...", "..."];
}
```

However, the Models directory is already reserved for ORM models.

How should such classes as PlotOptions be categorized and in which directory should they be stored?

Comment: Likely an opinion based deal, but will that be used with other Models? If so, you could create a `Models/Support` sub-directory and put things such as that there. The idea here is support things for models, if that is the intent, I don't believe there is a hard and fast rule.

Comment: @PaulT.
The PlotOptions class will be used for validation, filtering, searching and similar operations. In other words, the class **is** intended to be reused.
Your comment, even if it is only opinion based, helped me considerably in making up my mind. Thank you.

Comment: i think you might want to consider creating a separate directory, possibly named Helpers, Utilities, or Data, to store classes like your PlotOptions. This directory can be used for utility classes, configuration classes, or any other classes that do not fit neatly into the Models directory and are not strictly part of the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just create a folder in the app directory and put a namespace like

```
namespace App\ExampleFolder;
```

then you can access the class by using

```
use App\ExampleFolder\PlotOptions;
```